# Space cause issue in Sqlite DB search

Tags: android, search, android-sqlite

I have try to use this query

```
SELECT * FROM DBNAME WHERE NAME LIKE '%SEARCHKEYWORD%'
```

to implement a search in SQLite DB, but if Name contains spaces doesn't works, 
for example, if in the DB there is an item with Name **Mustang GT**, 
if I input the keyword `mustang gt` or `Mustang GT`... returns always empty query.

Comment: are you putting the single quotation marks around the search keyword when you do your query?

Comment: I pass the searchkeyword that is a String in this query that works only if the searchkeyword is without any space, as described

Comment: Yes, but you must surround it with single quotations. So, say you're passing in a String variable named searchKeyword. You must surround it in single quotations int he SQLite query. So, it should be WHERE NAME LIKE "'"+searchKeyword+"'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason that can lead to the describer problem in your code, probably something goes wrong when you get the String.

Try to  print the `SEARCHKEYWORD` to verify that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make both the column and string lower (or upper) case, as LIKE is case-sensitive.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM DBNAME WHERE lower(NAME) LIKE lower('%SEARCHKEYWORD%')
```

Comment: isn't case sensitive... the problem is the space